# How to find the first item according to a specific ordering using LINQ in O(n)?

Tags: c#, linq, complexity-theory, sql-order-by

Suppose I have a list of items (e.g., Posts) and I want to find the first item according to some non-trivial ordering (e.g., PublishDate and then CommentsCount as a tie-breaker).
The natural way to do this with LINQ is like this:

```
posts.OrderBy(post => post.PublishDate).ThenBy(post => post.CommentsCount).First()
```

However, the micro-optimizer in me is worried that calling OrderBy actually costs me O(n*lgn) for sorting the entire list, when all I really need is an O(n) find-minimum operation.

So, is LINQ smart enough to return something from OrderBy() that knows how to optimize subsequent First() calls? If not, what's a better way to do this out-of-the-box? (I can always write my own FindMinimumItem implementation but that seems like overkill).

Comment: if the key is actually as printed you do not need the ThenBy but could instead create a coumpund key of the two. Which would be easy since the first is either a long (tick) or a fixed with string. and that would infact be O(n) which you request but then again there's no garanty that O(n) is faster than O(nlogn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sorting is smart in the way that it will only do the `ThenBy` on the first group from the `OrderBy`, but the `OrderBy` still has to sort all items before it can return the first group.

You can use the Aggregate method to get the first post according to a custom comparison:

```
Post lowest =
  posts.Aggregate((Post)null,
    (x, y) =>
      x == null
      || y.PublishDate < x.PublishDate
      || (y.PublishDate == x.PublishDate && y.CommentsCount < x.CommentsCount)
      ? y : x
  );
```

(Assuming that you are using LINQ to Objects of course.)

Answer (score 2):

Is this in SQL or LINQ to Objects? If it's the latter, you probably want `MinBy` from [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/); your statement as written will indeed sort and then take the first item.

And yes, it's a shame that it doesn't include this (and similar things like `DistinctBy`) out of the box.

EDIT: I see your question has now changed; MoreLINQ doesn't support a compound comparison like that. In [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) I have code to create a compound `IComparer<T>` - you could pass that into `MinBy` using the identity function as the key selector. Feel free to add a feature request for a `MinBy` which takes a source and an `IComparer<T>` without a key selector :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at these. It's really a shame that there's no out-of-the-box way to convert between sets of key expressions (e.g. as used with OrderBy...ThenBy) and an IComparer.

Comment: An alternative to `ThenBy` could be returning a tuple: `Tuple.Create(post.PublishData, post.CommentsCount)`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually that is a `max` or `min` (I don't know the how is it called in LinQ), given a specific key; sorting and getting the first or last seems overkill in any language or framework.

Comment: The methods which take keys in LINQ unfortunately return the maximum/minimum key itself rather than the object containing that key.

Comment: cannot you make a composed key then? In python it's very typical to arrange a temporary tuple that contains the key and the whole record, since they are compared lexicographically.

Comment: Although .NET 4.0 has a Tuple type, .NET 3.5 doesn't. It's possible that this approach would work in .NET 4.0, but I'm not sure it's very idiomatic.

Comment: Well theoretically I could use anonymous objects as tuples, but then we're back at square one since I can only compare the key property and get the Min or Max of that.

Comment: Also, I doubt tuples in .NET 4 compare lexicographically (member-wise); that seems pretty pythonic ("let's do the reasonable thing by default") but not very C#-ish ("let's not do anything by default and force the code to be explicit and somewhat more readable").